# Prevent htaccess from affecting ajax requests

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to modify my htaccess request, it currently loads all the files that are php, but removes the .php extension. However I noticed that this affects my ajax requests, as I cannot get any POST data from them. What do I add to my htaccess to prevent a specific php(data.php) from not being affected by the extension removal of the htaccess?

The code of my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: may be you sending some data on post then check in htaccess if url with data then ignore rewrite or use post url in ajax without php extension like url/data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be you sending some data on post then check in htaccess if url with data then ignore rewrite or use post url in ajax without php extension like url/data

```
 url: data, //instaed of data.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip POST requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```